# Appium's element.clear() on a password TextBox doesn't work (on Android 6.0)

Tags: java, android, appium

I have noticed that in order to clear a textBox, Appium uses select all first, then deletes it. On Android 6.0 the select all option doesn't exist on this password textBox. Is there any other way to do that? Someone ran into this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i had faced same issue few days back.

I had observed that, even if you manually try to select full password, it will not do it, so you can't use select all, below code lines worked for me

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.HOME,Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT,Keys.END),"55");
```

or

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.HOME,Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT,Keys.END),"your string");
```

Let me know if it works for you as well!!

As per my research on this, this is a pending bug with Appium.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this problem. I'm using Android 6.0.1. For the password field, I directly use element.sendKeys method. Even when there is some value already there in the password field, sendKeys first selects the entire value, then deletes it and then finally writes the new value.

So I have not used element.clear() at all and it works fine in my case.